# Unable to start Evaluation process on jbpm

Tags: java, wildfly, jbpm, kie, drools-guvnor

I just started jbpm tutorial here https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStartedUsingSingleZipDistribution.html

Was able to start the server (after some suffering due to Reflection / access restrictions after java 9) .. then I went with the first step to open and deploy the sample process provided (Evaluation process)

https://youtu.be/-fxL2iioPRI

I got an error message on the business-central screen while trying to open the process : error retrieving datatypes

I checked the logs, It is not very useful, I wonder where I can look and trace the issue

```
 14:49:06,862 INFO  [org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder] (EJB default - 2) Incremental build request being processed: default://master@MySpace/Evaluation_Process/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml (added).
14:49:06,888 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2) java.lang.IllegalStateException: size = 2
14:49:06,889 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.matcher.FilterableList$AbstractBase.getOnly(FilterableList.java:139)
14:49:06,889 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.implementation.InvocationHandlerAdapter.apply(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java:235)
14:49:06,889 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.implementation.InvocationHandlerAdapter$ForInstance$Appender.apply(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java:362)
14:49:06,889 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:713)
14:49:06,889 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:698)
14:49:06,889 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:605)
14:49:06,916 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2)   ... 93 more
14:49:06,916 ERROR [org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder] (EJB default - 2) An error occurred while executing the Local Source Config stage.: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing the Local Source Config stage.
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.continuePipeline(PipelineExecutor.java:126)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.execute(PipelineExecutor.java:76)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildPipelineInvoker.java:88)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildServiceHelper.java:156)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.localBuild(BuildServiceHelper.java:67)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.localBuild(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl.build(BuildServiceImpl.java:64)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.build(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder$1.execute(ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder.java:132)
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${input.root-path}
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor.apply(LocalSourceConfigExecutor.java:51)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor.apply(LocalSourceConfigExecutor.java:33)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.apply(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.lambda$continuePipeline$0(PipelineExecutor.java:114)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:38)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:33)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.continuePipeline(PipelineExecutor.java:94)
        ... 86 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${input.root-path}
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2966)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3137)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3219)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3178)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)
        ... 93 more

14:49:10,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) java.lang.IllegalStateException: size = 2
14:49:10,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.matcher.FilterableList$AbstractBase.getOnly(FilterableList.java:139)
14:49:10,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.implementation.InvocationHandlerAdapter.apply(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java:235)
14:49:10,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.implementation.InvocationHandlerAdapter$ForInstance$Appender.apply(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java:362)
14:49:10,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:713)
14:49:10,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:698)
14:49:10,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:605)
14:49:10,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5133)
14:49:10,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1933))
.
.
14:49:10,146 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${input.root-path}
14:49:10,146 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
14:49:10,146 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor.apply(LocalSourceConfigExecutor.java:51)
14:49:10,147 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor.apply(LocalSourceConfigExecutor.java:33)
14:49:10,147 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.apply(Unknown Source)
14:49:10,147 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.lambda$continuePipeline$0(PipelineExecutor.java:114)
14:49:10,147 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:38)
14:49:10,147 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:33)
14:49:10,147 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.continuePipeline(PipelineExecutor.java:94)
14:49:10,148 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.execute(PipelineExecutor.java:76)
14:49:10,148 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildPipelineInvoker.java:88)
14:49:10,148 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(Unknown Source)
14:49:10,148 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildServiceHelper.java:189)
14:49:10,148 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.localBuildAndDeploy(BuildServiceHelper.java:143)
14:49:10,148 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.localBuildAndDeploy(Unknown Source)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl.buildAndDeploy(BuildServiceImpl.java:101)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl.buildAndDeploy(BuildServiceImpl.java:84)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildAndDeploy(Unknown Source)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
14:49:10,149 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.AbstractRPCMethodCallback.invokeMethodFromMessage(AbstractRPCMethodCallback.java:65)
.
.
14:49:10,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${input.root-path}
14:49:10,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   ... 93 more
```

I doubt the issue is with db configuration (not sure) ... it is using h2 by default as I learned.

Edit: I switched to local postgres 15, problem is still there

jvm: openjdk 16
bpm: latest 7.7.3.0
OS: windows

Answer (score 0):

I see the error message:

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.default:artifact:pom:1.0.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Remote host terminated the handshake

which points to an SSL issue with certificates or a proxy setting.